# Duplicate an Entire Row when a condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to duplicate a row when a condition is met, I search around and have built this code.

***What I want my code to do is to duplicate a row if the length of value in a cell of column C is more than 15 duplicate 1 time and if more than 30 duplicate it 2 times***, it will create a copy right below it then proceeds to the next row and so on, in a loop until the end.

This is what my initial code is:

```
Dim ia, iaLastrow As Long

    iaLastrow = ShtData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For ia = 2 To iaLastrow

        If Len(ShtData.Cells(ia, 3).Value) > 15 Then

            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Offset(1).Insert
            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).Offset(1)

        End If

    Next ia
```

I think my code is missing something, it creates a row but after the first occurence has been searched it duplicates until the end of data.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have done, a working code.

```
 Dim ia, iaLastrow As Long

    iaLastrow = ShtData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For ia = iaLastrow To 2 Step -1

        If Len(ShtData.Cells(ia, 3).Value) > 15 And Len(ShtData.Cells(ia, 3).Value) < 30 Then

            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Offset(1).Insert
            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).Offset(1)

        ElseIf Len(ShtData.Cells(ia, 3).Value) > 30 Then

            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Offset(1).Insert
            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).Offset(1)

            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Offset(2).Insert
            ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).Offset(2)

        End If

    Next ia
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the for loop

```
Dim ia, iaLastrow As Long

ibLastrow = ShtData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For ia = iaLastrow To 2 step -1

    If Len(ShtData.Cells(ia, 3).Value) > 15 Then

        ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Offset(1).Insert
        ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ShtData.Cells(ia, 1).Offset(1)

    End If

Next ia
```

Comment: that really works, I didn't know that could be done in for loop. thanks

Comment: it also works well when deleting an entire row, this trick is awesome. thanks